Bandsaw blade jumping off with a "thunk"
I've got one of the cheap generic bandsaws similar to the Clarke CBS205. Had it a few years, haven't done much with it and it has sat for a couple of years. I recently bought a new blade and took time over setting it all up properly and it's been working great for a couple of weeks. Today after using it for a short while with no issues it suddenly started 'thunk'-ing and then the blade came off. Over about an hour I checked and tried everything and now it just runs for about 2 seconds before doing it. The top wheel rubber belt seems to be bunching up on the wheel behind the blade.
Question : Is this worn tyres? If so, does anyone know what size they are so I can purchase some from Amazon / ebay?
Many thanks!

Welcome to WSE.  Something is clearly wrong with the tires, they should not "bunch up".  It is not possible to help without specific information and a photo or two.  What specifically have you tried?  Is this a new saw?  Have you checked with the manufacturer?

In addition to the above, have you tried asking this elsewhere (I mean, on a woodworking forum)? Just a photo or two of the problem and the overall bandsaw is likely to net you an answer or three on woodworking fora almost in real time because of the much larger memberships and a wide range of locations. Obviously we have the latter here, but not so much the former — until recently there were only 3-5 regular responders here.
